# How to make pan-core genome curve through command line on linux?

Tags: genome, metagenome

I´m working with a dataset of 566 genomes to analyze a pangenome. So I was working with PANWEB to create this pan core genome curve, however, there is too much sequence to work with this webserver. Well, specifically I´m looking for this kind of plot:
[image]

So, I just want to ask for some ideas of programs to do that with a big dataset and with a command line.

Here is the reference: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Pan-genome-and-core-genome-Graph-representing-the-pan-genome-blue-and-core-genome_fig1_317390138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `create_pan_genome_plots` from [Roary](http://sanger-pathogens.github.io/Roary/) can create a plot like this:
[image]